# How to check Dark Souls II global service availability?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2

The last few days I've received the dreaded

> The DARK SOULS II service is not available

message almost every time I open this game. To the best of my knowledge I'm not blocked in any way, I haven't changed any firewall settings lately, and I was able to play online for some time yesterday. [Bandai Namco support](https://support.bandainamcoent.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/438/0/dark-souls-ii---server-information) links to a [dead website](http://farfire.darksoulsii.com/pc/) for server status and their news page doesn't have *any* news since before the PC release, so I'm stumped: **Is the status of the Dark Souls II service available *anywhere*?**

Comment: I'm assuming this is on PC..?